# how do I store multiple uri values on an array?

Tags: c++, web, url, uri

I want to store on an `array`, multiple numbers passed on the **uri** of my **URL**, for example I have the url:

```
localhost:8000/234343,43456,7768
```

how do I store the numbers in array like this:

```
array[0]=234343
array[1]=43456
array[2]=7768
```

Comment: Just like that?

Comment: That's pretty much it. Declare your array then store your values.

Comment: how do I take the values from the uri one by one?

Comment: `std::getline` has a third parameter you can use to change the delimiter from the default `'\n'`. Pop the URL string into a `std::istringstream`, then use `getline` on the stream to peel out the tokens you want. `std::getline(steam, junkstring, '/')` gets you to the first token. `std::getline(steam, tokenstring, ',')` gets a token, and then convert `tokenstring` into a number with the appropriate conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that "," is the delimiter(the character separating the numbers) and you know how many are there, you can use string::find():

```
string array[3];
std::string uri = "localhost:8000/234343,43456,7768";
size_t pos = 0;
std::string delimiter = "/";
pos = uri.find(delimiter);
if (pos == std::string::npos)
   throw exception("bad uri");   
uri.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

delimiter = ",";
std::string token;
while ((pos = uri.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos && i < 3) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    array[i] = token;
    uri.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    i++;
 }
```